# How do BundleActivator, ManagedService, and my application interact on start/stop?

Tags: configuration, osgi, lifecycle

I had a non-OSGi application.  To convert it to OSGi, I first bundled it up and gave it a simple BundleActivator.  The activator's start() started up a thread of what used to be the main() of my app (and is now a Runnable), and remembered that thread.  The activator's stop() interrupted that thread, and waited for it to end (via join()), then returned.  This all seemed to be working fine.

As a next step in the OSGiification process, I am now trying to use OSGi configuration management instead of the Properties-based configuration that the application used to use.  So I am adding in a ManagedService in addition to the Activator.

But it's no longer clear to me how I am supposed to start and stop my application; examples that I've seen are only serving to confuse me.  Specifically, here:

http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-config-admin.html

They no longer seem to do any real starting of the application in BundleActivator.start().  Instead, they just register a ManagedService to receive configuration.  So I'm guessing maybe I start up the app's main thread when I receive configuration, in the ManagedService? They don't show it - the ManagedService's updated() just has vague comments saying to "apply configuration from config admin" when it is passed a non-null Dictionary.

So then I look here:

http://blog.osgi.org/2010/06/how-to-use-config-admin.html

In there, it *seems* like maybe they're doing what I guessed.  They seem to have moved the actual app from BundleActivator to ManagedService, and are dealing with starting it when updated() receives non-null configuration, stopping it first if it's already started.

But now what about when the BundleActivator's stop() gets called?

Back on the first example page that I mentioned above, they unregister the ManagedService.  On the second example page, they don't show what they do.

So I'm guessing maybe unregistering the ManagedService will cause null configuration to be sent to ManagedService.updated(), at which point I can interrupte the app thread, wait for it to end, and then return?

I suspect that I'm thoroughly incorrect, but I don't know what the "real" way to do this is.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

BundleActivator (BA) and ManagedService (MS) are callbacks to your bundle. BundleActivator is for the active state of your bundle. BA.start is when you bundle is being started and BA.stop is when it is being stopped. MS is called to provide your bundle a configuration, if there is one, or notify you there is no configuration.

So in BA.start, you register your MS service and return. When MS is called (on some other thread), you will either receive your configuration or be told there is no configuration and you can act accordingly (start app, etc.)

Your MS can also be called at anytime to advice of the modification or deletion of your configuration and you should act accordingly (i.e. adjust your app behavior).

When you are called at BA.stop, you need to stop your app. You can unregister the MS or let the framework do it for you as part of normal bundle stop processing.